# React: download a pdf file onClick with props and react-pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I want to generate a pdf based in props from the UI and download it. 
The props data will be fetched from an API after button click 
Having a document like this.

```js
const MyDoc = ({ text = "default" }) => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text>dsdsds{text}</Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

- Using PDFViewer,can update or refresh the viewer?

```js
const [text, setText] = useState("state");

  function change(){
    setText("updateText")
  }

  return (
    <>
      <PDFViewer width="100%" height="850px">
        <MyDoc text={{text}}/>
      </PDFViewer>
      <button onClick={change}>change props</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

- Using BlobProvider,can update or refresh the URL?

```js
const [text, setText] = useState("state");

  function change(){
    setText("updateText")
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BlobProvider
       document={<MyDoc text={{text}}/>} >
              {({ url }) => (
                <a
                  href={url}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer noopener"
                >
                  <b>Go to PDF</b>
                </a>
              )}
       </BlobProvider>
       <button onClick={change}>change props</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

- I don't think it will be possible using PDFDownloadLink, but neither with pdf method or usePDF hook

```js
const blob = pdf(MyDoc).toBlob();
//how can I add props to MyDoc
```

```js
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: MyDoc });
//how can I add props to MyDoc

  function change(){
    updateInstance({ document: MyDoc });
  }


  if (instance.loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>;

  if (instance.error) return <div>Something went wrong: {error}</div>;

  return (
    <>
     <a href={instance.url} download="test.pdf">
      Download
     </a>
     <button onClick={change}>change props</button>
    </>
  );
```

Or is there any other simpler way with react-pdf or am I using react wrong, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

use the fetch api to achieve as below

```
  const onButtonClick = () => {
fetch(decodeURI(`url`)).then((response) => {
  response.blob().then((blob) => {
    const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    console.log(fileURL)
    let alink = document.createElement('a')
    alink.href = fileURL
    alink.download = 'pdf_title'
    alink.click()
  })
})
```

}

Comment: How can I use fetch with react-pdf?, the pdf is build in client side with db data.

Answer (score 0):

> React: download a pdf file onClick with props and react-pdf?.

#### Create a document component and pass props as below

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4">
      <View >
        <Text>{data.text}</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

#### use react-pdf *PDFDownloadLink* to create a download link for your pdf above

```
<PDFDownloadLink
    document={
        <Document
              author=''
              keywords=''
              subject=''
              title=''
            >
              <MyDocument size='A4' />
            </Document>
          }
          fileName='mypdf.pdf'
        >
          {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
            loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!'
          }
        </PDFDownloadLink>
```